# How can I find groups with more than one rows and list the rows in each such group?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table "mytable" in a database. Given a subset of the columns of the table, I would like to group by the subset of the columns, and find those groups with more than one rows:

For example, if the table is

```
col1 col2 col3
1      1      1
1      1      2
1      2      1
2      2      1
2      2      3
2      1      1
```

I am interested in finding groups by col1 and col2 with more than one rows, which are:

```
col1 col2 col3
1      1      1
1      1      2
```

and

```
col1 col2 col3
2      2      1
2      2      3
```

I was wondering how to write a SQL query for that purpose?
Is the following the best way to do that?

First get the col1 and col2 values of such groups:

```
SELECT col1 col2 COUNT(*)
FROM mytable
GROUP BY col1, col2
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Then based on the output of the previous query, manually write a query for each group:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE col1 = val1 AND col2 = val2
```

If there are many such groups, then I will have to manually write many queries, which can be a disadvantage.

I am using SQL Server.

Comment: Classic way: `select * from T t1 where (select count(*) from T t2 where t2.col1 = t1.col1 and t2.col2 = t1.col2) > 1`

Answer (score 3):

The window function sum() over() may help here

**Example**

```
with cte as (
Select *
      ,Cnt = sum(1) over (partition by Col1,Col2) 
 From YourTable
)
Select *
 From  cte 
 Where Cnt>=2
```

**Results**

[image]

Another option (less performant)

```
Select top 1 with ties *
 From  YourTable
 Order By case when sum(1) over (partition by Col1,Col2) > 1 then 1 else 2 end
```

Results

[image]

Comment: While `sum(1)` is perfectly valid, `count(*)` is too and may be more intuitively obvious to a maintainer later. Unless I'm missing something?

Comment: @BenThul You are correct, but this falls into the "Style Bucket".  It may catch someone's attention for about half a second  :)

Answer (score 3):

This is a common problem.  One solution is to get the "keys" in a derived table and join to that to get the rows.

```
declare @test as table (col1 int, col2 int, col3 int)
insert into @test values (1,1,1),(1,1,2),(1,2,1),(2,2,1),(2,2,3),(2,1,1)

select t.*
from @test t
inner join (
    select col1, col2
    from @test
    group by col1, col2
    having count(*) > 1
    ) k
on k.col1 = t.col1 and k.col2 = t.col2
```

```
col1        col2        col3
----------- ----------- -----------
1           1           1
1           1           2
2           2           1
2           2           3
```